# I went AES encryption in java convert and use to flutter

Tags: java, flutter, encryption, aes

I have some code for encryption data in **java** with **salt** and **key**

```
Encryption.Builder builder = new Encryption.Builder()
        .setIv(new byte[16])
        .setKey("encry")
        .setSalt(salt)
        .setKeyLength(128)
        .setKeyAlgorithm("AES")
        .setCharsetName("UTF8")
        .setIterationCount(16)//65536
        .setDigestAlgorithm("SHA1")
        .setBase64Mode(Base64.DEFAULT)
        .setAlgorithm("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        .setSecureRandomAlgorithm("SHA1PRNG")
        .setSecretKeyType("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");


  Encryption encryption = builder.build();
  System.out.println("decryptedEnc = " + enc);
  String decrypt = encryption.decryptOrNull("9iLnZQjN2aZoCs04lkWw3HX2xb6io8ouND7VhhfeIYsKhUCjPHgThL3IeIiEPBmpwGkAKoIFvJidsa3rancHJoYy2e3ipj5zw+e2L7va5qA=");
  System.out.println("decrypted = " + decrypt);
  return decrypt;
```

and I decrypt data to flutter , But I can't found answer this question

please help me

tnx a lot

Comment: Do you mean you want to encrypt the data with java and  then decrypt with dart (in flutter)? Can you elaborate more about your question?

Comment: @CbL  yes , please help  me